# syncing the views of two angular apps

Tags: angularjs

I have two angular applications in one page, and I need them to communicate. Specifically, I want one application to use a service of another application.
I am able to get the service of the other application using Injector.get(service), but when I change the data using the service in one application, it does not reflect in the view of the other, even though both are supposed to show the same data. You can see a simplified version of the problem in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TVRPT/).
To save you the click, this is the relevant script:

```
    //myAppLeft - an angular app with controller and service
    var myAppLeft = angular.module('myAppLeft', []);

    myAppLeft.factory('Service1',function(){
        var serviceInstance = {};
        serviceInstance.data = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

        serviceInstance.remove = function(){
            serviceInstance.data.pop();
            console.log(serviceInstance.data);
        };
        return serviceInstance;
    } );
    myAppLeft.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', 'Service1', function($scope, service1) {
        $scope.data = service1.data;
        $scope.changeData =function(){
            service1.remove();
        }
    }]);
    var leftAppInjector = angular.bootstrap($("#leftPanel"), ['myAppLeft']);

    //myAppRight = an angular app with controller which uses a service from myAppLeft
    var myAppRight = angular.module('myAppRight', []);

    myAppRight.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = leftAppInjector.get('Service1').data;
        $scope.changeData =function(){
            leftAppInjector.get('Service1').remove();
        }
    }]);

    var rightAppInjector = angular.bootstrap($("#rightPanel"), ['myAppRight']);
```

I'd be happy to know why my code does not work as expected, and would be even happier to know if and how such thing can work.
I understand that if instead of two angular-apps I would have used one angular-app with two modules this would have worked just as I wanted, but unfortunately I cannot adopt this approach because my application consists of a pure-js core with extensions, each extension can be written in a different library/platform and I want my extensions to be angular ones.

Thanks,
Nurit.

Answer (score -1):

Angular apps are separate entities, even if you use the same service in both. the second app just initializes its own version off it.
What you want can be done using localStorage, and the [storage events](http://html5demos.com/storage-events).
Ping me if you need additional help on this!